# How do I code a redirect in an Angular page?

Tags: angular

In my new Angular 8 app I have a page (technically route) where a user selects one of 3 pages to go to in a radio button choice and based on her selection, gets redirected to her selected page. I know other web technologies (php, Coldfusion) had a simple redirect call, but how would I do this using routes? (Since the route has to load within the application....)

I suspect the answer lies in calling a route from within my if/else/elseif block (that simply traverses the user's possible selections)

```
if (radio_select_1) 
{redirect to page 1}
elseif (radio_select_2) 
{redirect to page 2}
else (radio_select_3) 
{redirect to page 3}
```

Based on the selected radio button I would expect to redirect the user to that page in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer https://angular.io/guide/router or https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5to full fill your requirement. I guess you have put the  inside your component. To simply answer the question you have to import the router module

```
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor( private router:Router) {
}
if (radio_select_1) 
{this.router.navigate(['page_1']);}
elseif (radio_select_2) 
{this.router.navigate(['page_2'])}
else (radio_select_3) 
{this.router.navigate(['page_3'])}
```

To do that you have to define the routes inside app.module.ts or in an imported route variable.

Comment: Thank you both for your helpful answers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import/inject the [`Router` module](https://angular.io/api/router/Router). Once you have that, you can redirect a couple of different ways.

Example:

```
export class MyComponent {
    private _router: Router;
    constructor(_router: Router) {
        this._router = _router;
    }
    doRedirect(url): Promise<void> {
        await this._router.navigateByUrl(url);
    }

}
```

**OR** redirect directly in your router module

```
  {
    path: 'redirectroute',
    redirectTo: '/some/path',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

**NOTE** that `url` for the redirect needs to be a *route*. If it's an external url, unfortunately you're going to have to use `window.location.href = url;`